# JavaFX: performance related to window size

Tags: java, performance, javafx, rendering, openjfx

I'm experiencing poor performance of JavaFX when the size of a Stage increases, even if only a small portion of the area changes.

The following example updates only a little square of 25x25, changing its background.

```
public class WindowSizeTest extends Application {

    private int speed = 1500000000;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane content = new StackPane();
        content.setPrefSize(25, 25);
        content.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                double val = ((double) now % speed) / speed;
                BackgroundFill backgroundFill = new BackgroundFill(Color.color(val, val, val), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY);
                Background background = new Background(backgroundFill);
                content.setBackground(background);
            }
        }.start();

        StackPane root = new StackPane(content);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Everything goes smoothly when the window is small:

[image]

..but..

if maximized on my 4k external monitor, it uses a lot my GPU and the performance of the entire system goes down:

[image]

It seems that JavaFX redraws the entire window content and not only the modified part (same behaviour on Windows).

Is this the expected behaviour? Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Kudos for the example but I cannot reproduce @ 5120 x 1440. Driver issue maybe? What GPU and drivers are you using?

Comment: I'm pretty sure is macos related, there are similar issues with applications like Intellij Idea on large resolutions on macos

Comment: I tested the code on several computers, and I always got the same results. I used MacBook Pro 13" with Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655, MacBook Pro 15" with Radeon Pro 560X, Dell Precision 5510 (Win 10) with Intel HD Graphics 530 and NVIDIA Quadro M1000M @ 3840x2160, MSI (Win 10) with NVIDIA GTX960 @ 1920x1080. Unfortunately it is not only a MacOS issue and it's not related to a specific GPU or driver.